# whats the validity of wso2 session cookie

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am hitting different wso2 services programatically from java using Wso2 Admin services... As user clicks buttons , i am doing different admin services...its like Start , stop , is Alive etc

in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Calling+Admin+Services , there is a session cookie generation..like

> Authenticate yourself and get the session cookie.

Can i just keep this session cookie for how long? is there an expiry?If i am doing many operation , can i just keep using it? 
If i have multiple WSO2 servers [ESB,APIM] etc , should it be different for each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default session timeout is 15 minutes. You can keep using it for the requests on the same server only.

Comment: Is this configurable ?

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 IS, when as SSO session is created with SSO protocols including SAML2SSO, OpenID Connect, a session cookie is created. This cookie is used as the session identifier and will be stored in the browser. From WSO2 IS side, session data is stored against this session id.

This cookie has a timeout value, which is 15 minutes by default. This means if the wso2is did not retrieve any SSO authentication requests for 15
minutes, the session would be timed out.

The timeout value is configurable. In `<IS-HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` file you can find the below config.

```
<TimeConfig>
        <SessionIdleTimeout>15</SessionIdleTimeout>
................
```